# Render raw HTML without v-html in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

The solution for the Vue is [VHTML](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@staszek998/v-html). But if we try to use it in Nuxt, we'll get

```
client.js?1d97:57 [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the 
template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, 
or use the compiler-included build.

(found in <Root>)
```

I tried below solution (suggested [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1142#issuecomment-317272538))

```js
build: {
 extend(config) {
  config.resolve.alias['vue'] = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
 }
}
```

but it has not solved the problem.

More outputs:

```
vue.common.dev.js?4650:6460 Mismatching childNodes vs. VNodes:  NodeList(2) [comment, comment] (117) [VNode, VNode, VNode, VNode, VNode, VNode, VNode, VNode, VNode, ....
```

```
[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content.
This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. 
Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

Comment: Can you share your template code?

Comment: @NickDawes It's just `VHTML(:html="arbitraryHTML")`. My `arbitraryHTML` is being rendered wihtout errors when `div(v-html="arbitraryHTML")`.

Comment: You're using pug on top of that?

Comment: @kissu, Of course it is not the root element of the component but all other code works correctly so I suppose it does not matter.

Comment: It can actually matter depending on what you have in your template exactly. Btw, did my answer helped somehow?

Comment: @kissu, Although I thank you for your answer, afraid no yet. I `v-html` is no option because it irequires of adding of new wrapper while here we are talking about how to avoid this wrapper. `<client-only>` breakes the SEO, so it is not the universal solution.

Comment: I can't see your template and I don't really understand why you could not use `v-html` here, what's the issue with it? Also, having a sanitizing wrapper is not a bad thing IMO, since it's related your app's security. But you do you at the end!

Comment: @kissu, I very thanks to Vue about it sanitizing my HTML by `v-html` and even want it. By why `div` or another element is requires for this? I was completely satistied and did not ask this question if `template(v-html)` worked but for some irrational reazon it does not works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the first issue, we'll need to check your `nuxt.config.js` and `package.json` to fix this one or at least know how you've started your project.
The linked solution is from 2017, so probably not that relevant nowadays too.

Never heard of VHTML, I don't really see the point of it. It doesn't even sanitize the output and is an additional dependency to rely on. The benefits are not amazing neither, I would pass on this one.
I recommend the usage of the regular `v-html` and a sanitizer as shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67741038/8816585).

Also, the rest of your issue with the DOM mismatch is the usual issue when you're working with SSR.
Here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585) on how to solve this and also what is the cause.

TDLR: it's not a config issue but rather a template one.